# Engine log says that it has invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

In SQL Navigator when I run sql script without least() function, it runs ok, 
but in ORACLE BI(OBIEE) it says invalid relational operator
why it happens? version is Oracle Business Intelligence 12.2.1.2.0

```
and (SUBSTR(sb.subs_type,-5) in (:Brand) or least(:Brand) is null)
and (i.called in (:called) or least (:called) is null)
```

Comment: I've never used OBIEE for real but I did a course on it a long time ago :-/  Anyway, I don't think OBIEE uses bind variables, because data warehouse performance considerations are different from OLTP database. Instead you have to define Repository or Session Variables. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e10540/variables.htm#BIEMG363).

Comment: Using `in()` or `least()` with a bind variable doesn't really make much sense anyway; if you pass/bind a comma-separated list of values then that whole list is treated as a single string, it isn't automatically tokenized into multiple values.

Comment: "The queries are automatically generated based on a metadata layer" but when you are createing a data set manually, sql query, you have to do it on your own , isn't it?